# How to change color of LineSeries in Windows Phone 8.1 XAML ToolKit Chart?

Tags: c#, wpf, charts, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml-toolkit

I'm trying to set from the Code Behind a color of some line in Chart. I have searched for 3 hours how to do it and I couldn't find anything. Is it possible do to that? If it can't be do, please recommend another chart library where I can do that.

Thanks!

XAML

```
<Charting:Chart Title="Name" x:Name="LineChart" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Width="510" Height="450">
        <Charting:LineSeries Title="PB" IndependentValuePath="Name" DependentValuePath="Amount" IsSelectionEnabled="True"/>
        <Charting:LineSeries Title="Oil" IndependentValuePath="Name" DependentValuePath="Amount" IsSelectionEnabled="True"/>
    </Charting:Chart>
```

WPF

```
Random rand = new Random();
        List<FinancialStuff> financialStuffList = new List<FinancialStuff>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++ )
            financialStuffList.Add(new FinancialStuff() { Name = Convert.ToString(i), Amount = rand.Next(0, 200) });

        (LineChart.Series[0] as LineSeries).ItemsSource = financialStuffList;

        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
            financialStuffList[i].Amount = rand.Next(0, 50);
        (LineChart.Series[1] as LineSeries).ItemsSource = financialStuffList;



public class FinancialStuff
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Amount { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 Style style = new Style(typeof(Control));
 style.Setters.Add(new Setter(Control.BackgroundProperty, new  SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red)));
 style.Setters.Add(new Setter(Control.HeightProperty, 5));
 style.Setters.Add(new Setter(Control.WidthProperty, 5));
 series.DataPointStyle = style;
```

Have you tried this? Try to set it when you get the line here

```
 (LineChart.Series[0] as LineSeries).DataPointStyle = style;
```

You may also try the following XAML:

```
<charting:LineSeries.DataPointStyle>
   <Style TargetType="charting:LineDataPoint">
       <Setter Property="Width" Value="17" />
       <Setter Property="Height" Value="17" />
       <Setter Property="Background" Value="Lime"/>
   </Style>
</charting:LineSeries.DataPointStyle>
```

Comment: Olaru mircea thanks! XAML doesn't work i'm getting error like The member "DataPointStyle" is not recognized or is not accessible. 

The first option work but only for points on the line, it change color of points not color of the line. Do you know how to change it?

Answer (score 1):

If anyone has problems, with Olaru Mircea solution in here

```cs
Style style = new Style(typeof(Control));
 style.Setters.Add(new Setter(Control.BackgroundProperty, new  SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red)));
 style.Setters.Add(new Setter(Control.HeightProperty, 5));
 style.Setters.Add(new Setter(Control.WidthProperty, 5));
 series.DataPointStyle = style;
```

just modify it like this:

```
Style style = new Style(typeof(Control));
 style.Setters.Add(new Setter(Control.BackgroundProperty, new  SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red)));
 style.Setters.Add(new Setter(Control.HeightProperty, 5.0));
 style.Setters.Add(new Setter(Control.WidthProperty, 5.0));
 series.DataPointStyle = style;
```

The first threw an exception for me, but after using double values, it worked fine.